# How do I import Buffer in a Quasar application running Vite?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, quasar

I am trying to use the eth-crypto module in my Quasar app which uses Vite.

It is throwing errors due to not finding the Buffer object, which makes sense, since it's in the front end.

Is there a good way to import a polyfill?

So far, I've tried the following in my quasar.config.js file:

```
const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');
const path = require('path');
const buffer = require('buffer');

module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
...
    build: {
      target: {
        browser: [ 'es2019', 'edge88', 'firefox78', 'chrome87', 'safari13.1' ],
        node: 'node16'
      },

      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      // vueRouterBase,
      // vueDevtools,
      // vueOptionsAPI: false,

      // rebuildCache: true, // rebuilds Vite/linter/etc cache on startup

      // publicPath: '/',
      // analyze: true,
      env: {
        VUE_APP_API: ctx.dev
          ? 'http://localhost:3000'
          : 'https://prod.api.com'
      },
      rawDefine: {
        global: {},
        buffer: buffer,
        Buffer: buffer.Buffer
      },
      // ignorePublicFolder: true,
      // minify: false,
      // polyfillModulePreload: true,
      // distDir

      // extendViteConf (viteConf) {},
      // viteVuePluginOptions: {},

      vitePlugins: [
        ['@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n', {
          // if you want to use Vue I18n Legacy API, you need to set `compositionOnly: false`
          // compositionOnly: false,

          // you need to set i18n resource including paths !
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/i18n/**')
        }],
        [
          'vite-plugin-bundle',
          {
            entries: [

            ]
          }
        ]
      ],
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and I'm frankly not sure how to import the Buffer object so that it will be available to npm modules.

Comment: If the package allows, you could also try importing the minified version of the library. If you're using typescript you can fix the typings in a .d.ts file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and not really succeeding in fixing this through polyfill plugins.

I tried adding another boot file, as a 0 index in the quasar boot files array. I'm not getting the error anymore and it might work for you.

Inside I have:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

// @ts-ignore
window.Buffer = Buffer;
```

Overall, it's probably best to find a library that supports your environment.